# infix to postifx converter

Tags: java, postfix-notation, infix-notation

hello  everyone I have an infix to postfix converter here.
It is converting

```
4 - 9 * 11 + 155 * ( 21 - 17 )/ 3
```

to

```
4 9 11 155 21 17 3 - * + * -
```

so that is pretty close. It is right
for shorter expressions. Any thoughts?

```
public class ExpressionTools {
    static MyStack<String> operatorStack=new MyStack<String>();
    public static String infixToPostfix(String infix)throws Exception{
     Scanner tokenizer = new Scanner (infix);
        System.out.println("hi");
        String postFixExpression="";
        while (tokenizer.hasNext()){

            String temp=tokenizer.next();
            if(temp.charAt(0)>=48&&temp.charAt(0)<=57){
                for(int i=0; i<temp.length(); i++){
                    if(!Character.isDigit(temp.charAt(i))){
                        throw new PostFixException("Invalid expression"+temp);
                }
                }
                postFixExpression+=temp+" ";
            }

            else if(temp.equals('(')){
                operatorStack.push(temp);
            }
            else if(temp.equals("*")||temp.equals("+")||temp.equals("-")||temp.equals("/")){
                if(!operatorStack.isEmpty()){
                    while(operatorStack.isEmpty()&&operatorStack.peek().equals("*")||operatorStack.isEmpty()&&operatorStack.peek().equals("/")){
                        postFixExpression+=operatorStack.pop()+" ";

                    }
                }
                operatorStack.push(temp);
            }
            else if(temp.equals(")")){
                while(!operatorStack.isEmpty()){
                    if(!operatorStack.peek().equals("(")){
                        postFixExpression+=operatorStack.pop()+" ";
                    }
                    else{
                        operatorStack.pop();
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println(postFixExpression);
        }


            while(!operatorStack.isEmpty()){
                postFixExpression+=operatorStack.pop()+" ";
            }



    System.out.println("final postfix");
    System.out.println(postFixExpression);
    return postFixExpression;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through this code in your debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems here.

1. `operatorStack.isEmpty()&&operatorStack.peek().equals("*")` can never be true.
2. `operatorStack.isEmpty()&&operatorStack.peek().equals("/")` can never be true.
3. `else if(temp.equals('(')){` should be `else if(temp.equals("(")){`.
4. Your tokenizer doesn't separate `)` from `/`. You either need to add a space after the `)` or else use a better tokenizer.